# Curl multipart/form-data, возвращает 417 ошибку

Tags: php, curl

Здравствуйте !
Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка?

Проблема состоит в том что нужно сгенерировать POST-запрос (multipart/form-data) для загрузки картинки на сервер но после отправки возвращает 417 ошибку.

`------WebKitFormBoundaryibLm7G5cqxCOuAFy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1-g-0-032-oz-silver-valcambi-bullion-bar-999-rev.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg`

`тело картинки`

`------WebKitFormBoundaryibLm7G5cqxCOuAFy`

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scrid"`

`32482346-7100587438898460646`

`------WebKitFormBoundaryibLm7G5cqxCOuAFy--`

Мой код для генерации:

```
        $img = file_get_contents($path);

        $boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundaryLZI2dppfUIcXxqT0';
        $eol = "\r\n";

        $postdata = '';
        $postdata .= '--'.$boundary.$eol;
        $postdata .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scrid"'.$eol.$eol;
        $postdata .= $scrid.$eol;
        $postdata .= '--'.$boundary.$eol;
        $postdata .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'.$filepath.'"'.$eol;
        $postdata .= "Content-Type: {$imginfo['mime']}".$eol.$eol;
        $postdata .= $img.$eol;

        $postdata .= '--'.$boundary.'--';

        $headers = array(
            "Content-Length: " . strlen($postdata),
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLZI2dppfUIcXxqT0",
            "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
            "Origin:http://www.ebayclassifieds.com",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
            "Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*;",
        );

        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.ebayclassifieds.com/m/ImageUpload');
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->_cookieFilePath);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->_cookieFilePath);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.ebayclassifieds.com/m/PostAd?scrid=$scrid");
```

если же формировать запрос средствами curl (`postdata = array('file' => '@'.filepath, 'scrid' => $scrid)`) возвращает 500 ошибку.

Или может кто подскажет есть ли возможность просмотреть сгенерированный запрос до его отправки на сервер, что бы сравнить ответ браузера и посланного запроса.

Спасибо!

Хидеры:

```
  > POST /m/ImageUpload HTTP/1.1
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like      Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
  Host: www.ebayclassifieds.com
  Referer: http://www.ebayclassifieds.com/m/PostAd?scrid=32482880-  4640459038477850577
  Cookie:     a=v^Mg!!^e^MTQ2ODQxMjA5MDkxNw!!^i^MjM0NjI4NTU!^u^Ym9oZGFuLWhhbkBtYWlsLnJ1^sec^LTEzMzY4NjQ3MzU!^l^MQ!!^n^aGFuMjAxNg!!^s^YXNVLWNMU1FHT3hlcFZSRGtfTmU4bXEyT25KeFRubzZtQnV2NlFycVkxWQ!!; p=l^birmingham^g^
  Content-Length: 39315
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----   WebKitFormBoundaryLZI2dppfUIcXxqT0
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
  Origin:http://www.ebayclassifieds.com
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*;
  Expect: 100-Continue

  < HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed
  < Content-Type: text/html
  < Content-Length: 363
  < Cneonction: close
  < Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 12:14:51 GMT
  < Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
  * HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
  < 
 * Closing connection 1
```

Comment: Попробуйте `postdata = array('file' =>  new CURLFile($filepath), 'scrid' => $scrid)`

Comment: @ilyaplot , спасибо , но к сожалению возвратило 417 ошибку, если я делаю запрос на сервер но вместо тела картинки отправляю любое другое значение , от сервера приходит ответ в виде json(так и должно быть) но с ответом что неверный параметр для картинки. 

Если же пытаюсь вставить путь или же вытянуть текстовый вариант картинки (`$img = file_get_contents($filepath)`) то возвращает 417

Comment: Сложно сказать, я с API vk мучался долго, у меня на одном сервере работало только через @, на другом только через CurlFile. Возможно, зависит от версии php, а может еще из-за чего-то. Что говорит документация к api?

Comment: @ilyaplot это не работа через апи, всё в ручную

Comment: т.е. в оригинале работает через браузер? Есть вообще сценарий, когда сервер отвечает 200 на загрузку файла?

Comment: да.
возвращает 200 ответ если в переменную $img подставить строку `$postdata .= '1'.$eol;`, собственно символ может быть любым другим(н валидным для запроса).
тогда возвращает : `{"photos":"","baseUrl":"","message":"Image Upload Error.","fullUrl":"","zoomPhotoUrl":"","messageDesc":"Attachment request file is missing.","success":false}`

Comment: Смотрю документацию. http://www.ebayclassifieds.com/m/apiDocs/home Требуется заголовок Expect, но в коде не вижу, что бы он вообще передавался. Посмотрите внимательно, там подробно описано как загружать файлы на сервер. 417 это как раз означает, что сервер ждет этот заголовок, но не получает его. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#417

Comment: @ilyaplot, спасибо большое за подсказку! Я вообще не подозревал за апи по подгрузке картинок , стыд и позор мне :(

Comment: @ilyaplot ,  к сожалению их апишка закрыта.
в осонвном тексте я привел хидеры которые я отправляю и которые приходят.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено , нужно было в хидерах отправлять `Expect: 0` вместо `Expect: 100-Continue`

спасибо всем кто принял участие в обсуждении

Comment: А, если не посылать `Expect` header вообще?

Comment: @jekaby выкидывает 417, так как сервер ожидает этот хидер, если же в курле не указывать его и `curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`  установить в false то курл автоматически прописывает хидер в 100-Сontinue